# Include a CDF file in sites.google

Tags: cdf-format

I have a website on sites.google and I also have blog on wordpress. I would like to include some CDF files on them. How can it be done?

Comment: [not on Wordpress.com](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/can-i-embed-wolfram-cdf-files-in-my-blog) but possible on other sites running Wordpress.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 7):

This free video course available from Wolfram Training site goes through details of CDF web embedding:

[**Computable Document Format: Deploying Ideas to the Web**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/cdf002.html)

Word Press CDF embedding and some other platforms are discussed in detail. sites.google needs to be checked - but if it does work, then it will use same ideas as explained in the course. Most platforms I know use the same set of procedures. There are two main cases to be aware:

1) **Advanced site**: your site can host files and allow JS plugins - like full Word Press platform hosted on your own domain. Then you host CDF on your own site and use one of two:
   - Play directly with JS: [Web Delivery: Embedded and Full-Screen CDF](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery.html)
   - or use [Wolfram CDF Plugin form wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wolfram-cdf-plugin/)
   - [Here is an example](http://kaurov.com/wordpress/?p=797)

2) **Basic generic blog**: your site cannot host files and/or does not allow JS plugins. Then external storage and iframe tags can help. [Here is an example](http://cdfexamples.blogspot.com/)

You also maybe interested to take a look at: [CDF and MediaWiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/cdf-and-mediawiki). All of this is discussed in details in the linked video course.

Comment: What you did in the cdfexamples.blogspot.com is precisely the kind of thing I want, can you please elaborate how to do it?

Comment: @SthitadhiRoy the 1st link to the video I gave does exactly that. did you try to watch it?